# Ender 3 Pro distance between nozzle and bed too large

Tags: creality-ender-3

Even when trying to level the bed, the max I can get the bed to the nozzle is pretty large.  I cannot level any higher (please see pic).[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your springs are ***WAY*** too much compressed. Turn them loose into the "UP" direction till you are almost at the bed and then level your bed.

[image: THIS way]